# sendEmail error

Tags: 12.04, bash, scripts

Im getting the error while using sendEmail utility in my ubuntu machine.

```
$sendEmail -f xxx@y7mail.com -t xxx@y7mail.com -u test mail -m "YCDI azar" -s smtp.mail.yahoo.com:587 -xu azhar -xp PASSWORD -o tls=yes

Mar 12 09:02:58 azhar-virtualbox sendEmail[3644]: ERROR => Timeout while reading from smtp.mail.yahoo.com:465 There was no response after 60 seconds.
```

Comment: Can you `telnet smtp.mail.yahoo.com 465`? Is that connection timing out? If so, maybe there's some port filtering involved in your network.

Comment: `telnet smtp.mail.yahoo.com 587
Trying 217.146.190.250...
Connected to smtp.mail.global.gm0.yahoodns.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp.mail.yahoo.com ESMTP ready`                          telnet is working.

Comment: What about port 465? Sorry I edited my answer: your error message tells about an error on port 465.

Comment: `telnet smtp.mail.yahoo.com 465
Trying 106.10.150.171...
Connected to smtp.mail.global.gm0.yahoodns.net.
Escape character is '^]'.`   It is also working.

Comment: Help me on this...